# How to add external java library to custom Android framework?

Tags: android-source, android-framework

Can someone enlighten me on how to include an external java framework to android framework and compile it as a part of the custom android framework?

The idea is to make this external framework a part of my custom android framework and expose it as android service for other processes to use.

In essence what I did is -

1. checked for android port of the java framework
2. Copied the src dir (including all the external jar files) from the ported framework to `framework/base/core/java/android/`
3. Edited ActivityManager in the framework to call the copied library
4. run make

Is this the right approach to edit Android framework? Since, I am including the java files and associated external jars of the external project inside the Android framework I suspect make fails while converting the jars to dex.

Can somebody point me towards any available resources dealing with Android Framework internals and on how to edit Android framework?

I checked the `Tutorial: Android Internals - Building a Custom ROM, Pt. 2 of 2` on youtube from this year's Marko Gargenta presentation in Beijing, China. But he didn't make it (i.e. adding external framework or jars) clear either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First: I'm not very experienced in the Android build process, so there might be a better solution, but this one should work (at least for Android 2.2).

I assume, that you use Eclipse for the source code modification and already executed a successful `make -j4`...

- Create a new source folder: `external/<your-library>/src`
- Copy all Java source files into this folder.
- Open the following make file: `<android>/frameworks/base/Android.mk`
- Search for `# Build ext.jar` and add your library as follows:

  ```
  [...]
  ext_dirs := \
      ../../external/apache-http/src \
      ../../external/<your-library>/src \
      ../../external/gdata/src \
      ../../external/protobuf/src \
      ../../external/tagsoup/src
  [...]
  ```
- Now you should be able to access these libraries from the Android framework...
- Finally execute `make -j4 ext` to build only the external module,
- Or `make -j4` to build all changed files (if a previous build exists in `/out/`).

Comment: Would this work for a library jar, for instance, I want to include the Apache commons math library...

Answer (score 1):

[README.txt](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/vendor/sample/+/acd7c6b02a14e8694d0dced56ea37e79707fba1e/frameworks/PlatformLibrary/README.txt) from git repo in https://android.googlesource.com/platform/vendor/sample is a good example howto do it. It's good to clone it to see the examples.

Basically you need to create jar file and add it in filesystem, add xml configuration into `/system/etc/permissions/` and declare `<uses-library>` in apk's `AndroidManifest.xml`.

In my case I had problem with adding `<uses-library>` on a wrong place (not in `<application>`).

So it's good to check the result with:

```
$ aapt dump badging Foo.apk | grep uses-library
uses-library:'android.foo'
```